# jQuery validate, can't get it to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, jquery-validate

OK, beating my head against the Javascript/jQuery wall over here, 
[here](http://pastie.org/771558) is the code, which I simply can't get to work properly, any help is highly appreciated!

Especially this bugs me, changing row **60** from
`c.gbForm.validator = c.dom.gbForm.validate(c.gbForm.validator);` to
`c.gbForm.validator = $("#gbForm").validate(c.gbForm.validator);`
and row **61** from
`c.dom.gbForm.unbind('submit').submit(c.gbForm.doAdd);` to
`$("#gbForm").unbind('submit').submit(c.gbForm.doAdd);`
makes it kinda work, except then I get 
`this[0] is undefined error` which I think is the jQuery validate plugin but I simply can't locate the exact spot at fault... So any hints/pointers to why the whole "var c" business isn't working and the same for the "this[0]" part would be awesome!

Thanks for any assistance!
John

Comment: I presume the 2nd snippet has a syntax error from where you have typed it?

Comment: I would suggest just trying to get the validate to work without making all the extra objects.  Just try $("#gbForm").validate({}) with all of your rules, messages, etc.  Does that at least run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, here are a few things to look at

```
c.gbForm.validator = $("#gbForm").validate(c.gbForm.validator);
```

here you are referencing c.gbForm.validator before it is set (assuming this is the first assignment to c.gbForm.validator).

try this.

```
c.gbForm.validator = $("#gbForm");
c.gbForm.validator = $("#gbForm").validate(c.gbForm.validator);
```

also, why do you call c.doc.gbForm in one spot and just c.gbForm in another?

and as the comment says, validation should be as simple as $("gbForm").validate();